# Undefined Classes in Django 1.7 Migrations

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

I'm running into problems where old migrations contain references to classes or even modules that are no longer defined. What is the best way for me to resolve these issues?

I can get rid of the error messages by just removing these references, but what if I'm breaking the migrations?

Also am I the only person who thinks it's a little crazy that Django 1.7 migrations actually import parts of my codebase at all given that I'm obviously going to edit it?

Example error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/.../migrations/0001_initial.py", line 194, in Migration
bases=(model_utils.models.UserPersonMixin, models.Model),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UserPersonMixin'
```

In this case, UserPersonMixin is an abstract base class that this model used to inherit from but which I've recently trashed while reorganizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your migration you should access the historical models instead of importing the actual models as you usually do.

This is done to nto fall in the issue you have. To get the historical mdoels (i.e. a model which existed when you created such migration) you have to replace your code:

Check this from the official django docs ([this case is for data migrations althought the concept applies to your case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models, migrations

def combine_names(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Person = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Person")
    for person in Person.objects.all():
        person.name = "%s %s" % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
        person.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(combine_names),
    ]
```

This migration does a python code, and needs a certain model. To avoid importing models which are not existent anymore, it does not a direct import, but an "aggregated" access to the model in "that exact time slice". This code:

```
apps.get_model("yourappname", "Person")
```

would be an exact replacement of:

```
from yourappname.models import Person
```

since the latter would fail in a brand-new installation which has to run the migrations.

**Edit** please post the full code of your migration to see if I can help you with your particular case, since I have a project with models that aren't anymore (i.e. deleted) but have no such issue.

Comment: In my case, the migrations in question were created before I got rid of the models, so that's probably why I had the problem that I had. I like your solution though. I was looking through the documentation before posting this question but had difficulty finding this, so thanks for sharing!